# About the proof of nine-lemma using snake lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-explanation, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

I cannot follow the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006157/a-consequence-of-the-snake-lemma?newreg=c6c63f3f7e4d478fa5d80e37f52970a8) $(3\times 3)$ nine-lemma by using the snake lemma.

Is there another way to understand the commutativity of the diagram after replacing the morphisms coming from the snake lemma without the universal property of kernels and cokernels?

Comment: I mean you can do a tedious diagram chase to avoid the snake lemma. But I'm not sure if that's what you are looking for.